Waking from suspend taking a very long time (or not happening at all) 24.04
I have a Dell XPS 9315. I just upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04.
I have an issue with waking up from suspend. When I try to resume from suspend (e.g., opening the laptop lid or pressing a key on the keyboard), sometimes it takes 10+ seconds for it to wake up (to the lock screen). Other times, it just doesn't wake up at all. If I close and open my laptop lid a few times, then eventually it works (but still takes 10+ seconds for the lock screen to appear.
What can I do to fix this?

Within 5 minutes of one of these events, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system log messages. Read each one with care.

I am having the same exact issue, same laptop, same Ubuntu version.

Simliar issue with HP Elitebook.
In my syslog I have things like
wireplumber[2198]: Error opening low-level control device 'hw:0': No such file or directory and also wireplumber[2198]: Cannot open '/dev/video0': 13, Permission denied

Update: For me, this problem has been resolved by a recent software update
